# Alamofire POST Request PHP script gets no values

Tags: php, mysql, swift, alamofire

I have a problem with a POST request in Alamofire. If I try to make a POST Request, it seems that the PHP script doesn't get the values. This is my POST Request:

```
func userRegistration(){
    let url = "http://offlineshopper.sunpowr.de/register.php"
    let parameters: [String:String] = ["nickname":RegisterTexts.nickname, "password":RegisterTexts.password, "email":RegisterTexts.email]
    print(parameters)
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{ response in
        if((response.result.value) != nil){
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print("Das kommt dabei raus: \(swiftyJsonVar)")
        }
    }
}
```

The parameters Dictionary print this: ["nickname": "Test", "password": "Test", "email": "Test"]

So I think this is right.

This here is my PHP Script:

```
<?php
include("mysql_connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['nickname'])){
    $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
}

if(isset($_POST['password'])){
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}

//Check if nickname is already used
$select = "SELECT `nickname` FROM `User` WHERE nickname = '$nickname'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $select);
if (!$result){
    $returnArray["message"] = "Fehler in der Datenbank!";
    json_encode($returnArray);
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){
    $returnArray["message"] = "Nickname bereits vorhanden!";
    json_encode($returnArray);
}

//Add new User to the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO User (nickname, password, email) VALUES ('$nickname', '$password', '$email')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    $returnArray["message"] = "Erfolgreich registriert!";
    echo json_encode($returnArray);
}
else{
    mysqli_error($link);
    $returnArray["message"] = "Fehler!";
    echo json_encode($returnArray);
}

mysqli_close($link)
?>
```

I get the response "Erfolgreich registriert" in my App so everything should work fine. I also get new datasets in my database. The problem is that only the id is set in the database, which is auto increment. The other fields are empty so the POST variables are never saved in the database.. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: It's working now, just switching

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON
```

with

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Thanks for the hints but this should only be a short test on how the interaction between Swift and Webservices work, I'm still learning. I would never publish this :) I know that authentication like this is very unsafe

Comment: If you want to do a test, that's fine. Just dummy in hard-coded passwords and forget your user table entirely. That way if that does slip into production for some reason (weird stuff happens in a chaotic world!) you're still okay.

Comment: I got the issue.. I just had to replace JSONEncoding.default with URLEncoding.httpBody

Comment: If you have a fix that works, might want to self-answer to formalize it. Good work!